# How could I display the hierarchy from a database with hierarchical data in Liferay 6.2 or 7.2?

Tags: liferay, hierarchy, liferay-6, hierarchical-data, liferay-7

I would like to display hierarchical data in Tree view in UI. Does Liferay 6.2 or 7.2 support it?

Comment: Did you try it? What does the documentation of Liferay 6.2 or 7.2 say about this?

Comment: As you can use various frontend frameworks such as metaljs, angular, react, jquery, aui and so on, you will probably find an appropriate TreeView component to be used with a lazy-load api comming from your liferay server

Comment: Thanks for your replies,@mkrieger1 didn't find a tree view in content in the documentation of Liferay. @Andre Albert could I create it for example in JS and after using api without having issues in liferay?

Comment: You would create a Rest (or any other remote API) endpoint in liferay (or use any existing if we talks about liferay entities here). You then have something like "getSubElementsForParentIdentifier" and handle this in you choosen TreeView component. I cant think of any issue concerning liferay. For this your question is too broad

Comment: _does_ Liferay support it? Sure. Just about any web markup that you can think of can be generated. _how_ would this be implemented? See [ask] - that's indeed far too broad